# create Divs With loop

Tags: javascript, html, web

how can i duplicate this code with for loop

```html
<div class="Post1">
  <div class="TopArea">
    <button class="Tags">Tech</button>
    <button class="Tags">Completed</button>
  </div>
  <p class="PostTitle">“At risus mauris velit elementum turpis sodales odio gravida porta nec quisque urna ornare justo id libero vel cursus tristique...”</p>
  <div class="BottomAre">
    <div class="user">
      <img src="/Svg/Dixit.png" class="UserImg">
      <span class="UserName">User01</span>
    </div>
    <button class="LikeBtn">
      <i class="bi bi-lightbulb"></i>
      <span class="TotalLike">20</span>
    </button>
    <button class="CommnetBtn">
      <i class="bi bi-chat-right-text"></i>
      <span class="TotalComment">20</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Simple Code Like This:--

```
for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
contain.innerHTML += "<div>heloo</div>";
}
```

Can generate Divs

but How can I generate a long code?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

- using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

I added a data example - fill in the missing data yourself

```js
const data = [{user:"user1",totalLike:20},
{user:"user2",totalLike:2},
{user:"user3",totalLike:3}
]
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data.map((item,i) => `<div class="Post${i}">
  <div class="TopArea">
    <button class="Tags">Tech</button>
    <button class="Tags">Completed</button>
  </div>
  <p class="PostTitle">“At risus mauris velit elementum turpis sodales odio gravida porta nec quisque urna ornare justo id libero vel cursus tristique...”</p>
  <div class="BottomAre">
    <div class="user">
      <img src="/Svg/Dixit.png" class="UserImg">
      <span class="UserName">${item.user}</span>
    </div>
    <button class="LikeBtn">
      <i class="bi bi-lightbulb"></i>
      <span class="TotalLike">$(item.totalLike}</span>
    </button>
    <button class="CommnetBtn">
      <i class="bi bi-chat-right-text"></i>
      <span class="TotalComment">20</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>`).join("");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Using template (according to your comment, not interesting):

- using [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const template = document.getElementById("tmpl")
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  const div = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  const firstDiv = div.querySelector("div");
  firstDiv.className = firstDiv.className.replace("X", i)
  const userSpan = div.querySelector(".user")
  userSpan.textContent = `User${i}`
  container.appendChild(div)
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<template id="tmpl">
<div class="PostX">
  <div class="TopArea">
    <button class="Tags">Tech</button>
    <button class="Tags">Completed</button>
  </div>
  <p class="PostTitle">“At risus mauris velit elementum turpis sodales odio gravida porta nec quisque urna ornare justo id libero vel cursus tristique...”</p>
  <div class="BottomAre">
    <div class="user">
      <img src="/Svg/Dixit.png" class="UserImg">
      <span class="UserName">UserX</span>
    </div>
    <button class="LikeBtn">
      <i class="bi bi-lightbulb"></i>
      <span class="TotalLike">20</span>
    </button>
    <button class="CommnetBtn">
      <i class="bi bi-chat-right-text"></i>
      <span class="TotalComment">20</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: i want to do like that with data fetched from data base

Comment: i exactly tired that but vs code was throwing errors

Comment: now i found i was just missed to put ; at last thas why vs code was showing error , also thanks @mplungjan and @ Kinglish for answering this que

Comment: I added a data example

Comment: @Raju You are welcome. Please [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, you could simply clone the HTML block you want to repeat using [cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), then [appendHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) it to the page

```js
let html = document.querySelector('.Post1');
let destination = document.querySelector('.newhtml');
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  // create the clone
  let newhtml = html.cloneNode(true)
  destination.appendChild(newhtml)
}
```

```html
<div class="Post1">
  <div class="TopArea">
    <button class="Tags">Tech</button>
    <button class="Tags">Completed</button>
  </div>
  <p class="PostTitle">“At risus mauris velit elementum turpis sodales odio gravida porta nec quisque urna ornare justo id libero vel cursus tristique...”</p>
  <div class="BottomAre">
    <div class="user">
      <img src="/Svg/Dixit.png" class="UserImg">
      <span class="UserName">User01</span>
    </div>
    <button class="LikeBtn">
        <i class="bi bi-lightbulb"></i>
        <span class="TotalLike">20</span>
      </button>
    <button class="CommnetBtn">
        <i class="bi bi-chat-right-text"></i>
        <span class="TotalComment">20</span>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='newhtml'> </div>
```

Comment: i also want to update data that are fetched from db